# how to use jenkins output in execute shell block to trigger next job

Tags: shell, jenkins

I have jenkins build console output of a job that i want to use in execute shell of the same job. The output is

```
POST Response Code: 200
Response: 
{"status":"success","results":{"job_id":"57","ip":null,"hostname":null}}
```

I want to use the status variable to print whether is is success or failure. How can I do that.

Im using echo "$status" its not working

Comment: Who produced the output? is that a plugin or a plugin or something else?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to break the job based on the value right?

You can sed the response:

```
echo '{"status":"success","results":{"job_id":"57","ip":null,"hostname":null}}'
    \ | sed -r 's|.+status":"(.+?)","r.*|\1|p'
```

Assign it to a variable and do whatever you want.

Otherwise you can use the [Text-finder Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Text-finder+Plugin). You assign the response of your action to a temporary file and let the plugin check for a phrase.